# Scala io.Source.fromfile not finding my file even with absolute path specified

Tags: scala, file-io, io

I am trying to access a file in Scala using `io.Source.fromfile`.
I have specified the full path, but i am still getting a `no such directory or file` error.

This is a general version of what my code looks like:

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("~/top/next/source/resources/desiredFile.txt").getLines()
```

I'm running Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably because you are using tilde sign, use full absolute path.
If you want to avoid hard coding your home directory, you can get it from environment variables:

```
val home = System.getProperty("user.home")
val s = Source.fromFile(s"${home}/.....").getLines()
```

Comment: meaning what exactly? Should I specify home/ instead of ~/?

Answer (score 5):

The compiler was assuming it should start in the project folder I was already in, so when I specified the directories above that folder, it tried to find them all as a sub-directory of my root project folder.
This would obviously cause an error.

I now have:

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("source/resources/desiredFile.txt")
```

which is working properly